# Get screen size with two monitor

Tags: vb.net

I using this code for get height an with of the screen size :

```
 Dim hdcSrc As IntPtr = User32.GetWindowDC(handle)       
 Dim windowRect As New User32.RECT
 User32.GetWindowRect(handle, windowRect)
 Dim width As Integer = windowRect.right - windowRect.left
 Dim height As Integer = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top
```

now,When we have two monitors of different sizes. Which is considered the default monitor?

Comment: You tried this? [Screen.PrimaryScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) and this [Screen.AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful class in the Net Framework that could easily substitute your code.

[Screen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And the primary screen is obtained using

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen
```

For example your code above is replaceable using

```
Dim area As Rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
Console.WriteLine("Width: " & area.Width.ToString)
Console.WriteLine("Height: " & area.Height.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

All this are available in the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Screen.AllScreens
```

And

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen
```